# Adding a new node to existing cluster

Tags: cassandra

Is it possible to add a new node to an existing cluster in cassandra 1.2 without running `nodetool cleanup` on each individual node once data has been added?

It probably isn't but I need to ask because I'm trying to create an application where each user's machine is a server allowing for endless scaling.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.  But you should be aware of the side-effects of not doing so.

`nodetool cleanup` purges keys that are no longer allocated to that node.  According to the [Apache docs](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/Operations), these keys count against the allocated data for that node, which can cause the auto bootstrap process for the *next* node to not properly balance the ring. So depending on how you are bringing new user machines into the ring, this may or may not be a problem.

Also keep in mind that `nodetool cleanup` only needs to be run on nodes that lost keyspace to the new node - i.e. adjacent nodes, not all nodes, in the cluster.